# How to create own "EditText" by extending View? How to handle/connect soft keyboard?

Tags: android, android-custom-view

i'd like to create my own EditText by extending View. (Extending TextView or EditText will be considered cheating ;-)

It will have simple functionality:

- get focus on touch and show soft input keyboard
- append touched char on keyboard to text
- delete last char of text if 'delete'-button on keyboard is touched

Right now, i'm wondering how to connect the soft keyboard events to my custom view?
Do you have any ideas? samples?

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who are interested in a possible solution:

I have overwridden the onCreateInputConnection() method in my view and created a MyInputConnection by subclassing the abstract input connection class. From then on, i was able to handle any soft input events in my view.

Comment: I am now in a similar situation and I can't resolve it. Can we discuss somewhere?

Comment: Christian, here is a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44536580/edittext-like-custom-view-creation-from-the-scratch-standard-view